# jQuery Loop through selects and set selected option

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to loop through all of the select inputs on a page and if the selected value is not a certain option then set that value to selected

I have some selects

```
<select name="select1">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2" selected>Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
  <option value="4">Four</option>
  <option value="5">Five</option>
</select>

<select name="select2">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
  <option value="4">Four</option>
  <option value="5">Five</option>
</select>

<select name="select3">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
  <option value="4">Four</option>
  <option value="5">Five</option>
</select>
```

I'm looping through them like so, but I can't figure out how to set the selected property to option '2' if it isn't already selected

```
$('select').each(function() {

    var selected = $(this).find(":selected");

    if (selected.val() != 2) {
        // do some stuff

    }

}
```

EDIT:

I should elaborate. If a select input value is changed, I'm appending a string e.g. '-updated' to the input value as each input will be posting off to a database. Ideally I'd only do this for inputs that have changed for efficiency

So I'd like to set all selects inputs that don't already have option 2 selected to be selected and have a value of "2-updated"

Thanks for all of the answers so far

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's already selected - just set it again and jQuery will deal with it for you. If you're setting them all to `2`, you don't even need the loop, just `$('select').val('2')`

Comment: `$('select').val('2');`

Comment: or you may want something `$('select:not(:has(:selected))').val('2');`

Comment: I should elaborate. If a select input value is changed, I'm appending a string e.g. '-updated' to the input value as each input will be posting off to a database. Ideally I'd only do this for inputs that have changed for efficiency

So I'd like to set all selects inputs that don't already have option 2 selected to be selected and have a value of "2-updated"

Thanks for all of the answers so far

Answer (score 2):

Find all options with value equal to 2 and select them:

```js
$('select').each(function() {
  $(this).find('option[value="2"]').prop('selected', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="select1">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3" selected>Three</option>
  <option value="4">Four</option>
  <option value="5">Five</option>
</select>

<select name="select2">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
  <option value="4">Four</option>
  <option value="5">Five</option>
</select>

<select name="select3">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
  <option value="4">Four</option>
  <option value="5">Five</option>
</select>
```

Comment: its been years after you answered this. But this answer gave the hint to my problem. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the desired option value to `.val()` method while targeting select to select required option element:

```
$('select').val('2');
```

**Working Snippet:**

```js
 $('select').val('2');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="select1">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3" selected>Three</option>
  <option value="4">Four</option>
  <option value="5">Five</option>
</select>

<select name="select2">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
  <option value="4">Four</option>
  <option value="5">Five</option>
</select>

<select name="select3">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
  <option value="4">Four</option>
  <option value="5">Five</option>
</select>
```

Comment: When I change a select input I append a string '-updated' to the value, is there any way I can set all selects that aren't already value=2 to value 2 and add this string to them? `function set_updated() {

  var inputname = $(this).find(":selected")[0].value;

  if (!inputname.match(/updated/i)) {

    $(this).find(":selected").val(inputname + "-updated");

  }

}`

Comment: No worries. On the form action of these select inputs I'd like to loop through and do some operations (web service/database call) which I have working in a separate PHP file, however I'd like to only do that where the inputs have been updated. Therefore when a select is changed I've added a string '-updated' to the option value like this - `<select name="select3">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2-updated">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
  <option value="4">Four</option>
  <option value="5">Five</option>
</select>`

Comment: How can I do that for select inputs that aren't already selected as value='2'?

Comment: @jdoe: like this http://jsfiddle.net/2d9ewvck/ . inspect element in console to see modified value.

Answer (score 1):

You can explore the `value` key of this jquery object

```
   $('select').each(function() {
    var selected = $(this)[0].value;
    console.log(selected)
    if (selected != 2) {
        alert("Not 2")

   }
})
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/50dgszyo/)

Comment: `$(this)[0].value;` can be replaced by `this.value`