# jQuery set all select inputs to certain value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to loop through all of the select inputs on a page and if the selected value is not a certain option then set that value to selected

I have some selects (notice in select1, option 2 is selected)

```
<select name="select1">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2" selected>Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
  <option value="4">Four</option>
  <option value="5">Five</option>
</select>

<select name="select2">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
  <option value="4">Four</option>
  <option value="5">Five</option>
</select>

<select name="select3">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
  <option value="4">Four</option>
  <option value="5">Five</option>
</select>
```

The idea here would be to have a checkbox that when it's checked set select2 and select3 to have option 2 selected as they don't have that option already selected and append a string to the value so I know they've been updated e.g '-updated'

I'm looping through them like so, but I can't figure out how to set the selected property to option '2' if it isn't already selected and then append '-updated' to the value

```
$('select').each(function() {

    var selected = $(this).find(":selected");

    if (selected.val() != 2) {
        // set option 2 as selected
        // append '-updated' to value

    }

}
```

Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/69zzr6xa/6/

Comment: Why not just set the value irrespective of it is already set or not? the code will become one line i.e `$('select').val(2)`.

Comment: This seems *exactly* the same as your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38565530/jquery-loop-through-selects-and-set-selected-option), just slightly re-worded? It would be best to delete this question and edit your previous one with more accurate details

Comment: On the form action I will loop through the inputs and then do a webservice/database call for each input. It would be ideal to only have to do a call where the input has changed as my page could potentially have hundreds of inputs

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan that advice could've been given without a downvote party on both of the questions surely?

Comment: If you're implying I downvoted you, I didnt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var selected = 0;
$('select').each(function(i) {
    var obj = $(this);
    if(i == 0) selected = $(this).find(":selected");
  
    if (obj.val() != 2) {
       if (obj.val().indexOf('-updated') < 0) {
         obj.val(selected.val());
         obj.find(":selected").text(selected.text()+" -updated");
       }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="select1">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2" selected>Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
  <option value="4">Four</option>
  <option value="5">Five</option>
</select>

<select name="select2">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
  <option value="4">Four</option>
  <option value="5">Five</option>
</select>

<select name="select3">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
  <option value="4">Four</option>
  <option value="5">Five</option>
</select>

<label>Set to two
  <input type="checkbox" id="set_to_two" name="set_to_two">
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check below example.

1. Loop through the `select` elements
2. Check if the value is already selected, if not set the value.

Also added the code to change other dropdown's, when any one is changed

```js
$(function() {
  var setValue = "2";

  /* Initialize the select's to base value */
  $('select').each(function() {
      $(this).val(setValue);
  });

  /* Change the values of select's when anyone of the select changes */
  $('select').change(function() {
    setValue = $(this).val();

    $('select').each(function() {
        $(this).val(setValue);
    });
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="select1">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2" selected>Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
  <option value="4">Four</option>
  <option value="5">Five</option>
</select>

<select name="select2">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
  <option value="4">Four</option>
  <option value="5">Five</option>
</select>

<select name="select3">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
  <option value="4">Four</option>
  <option value="5">Five</option>
</select>
```